# wsdl2java ObjectFactory not generating JAXBElement

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java, jaxbelement

I have generated java classes from wsdl file using the apache cxf. It generates the  JAXBElement. I make this as jar file and exposed as @WebService. If I generate the java files from the new wsdl, it doesn't generate teh necessary JAXBElement. Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are doing wsdl2java, java2wsdl and wsdl2java again?

Comment: Yes Dennis. I am doing wsld2java java2wsdl and wsdl2java using apache cxf.